# При запуске gulp получаю ошибку Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] - как её решить?

Tags: gulp, npm, gulp4

Хочу подключить gulp сборку для проекта отсюда [отсюда](https://github.com/agragregra/OptimizedHTML-5)
Выполняю команды:
**npm i**
**gulp**
и получаю ошибку, которая говорит о том, чтобы заменить *require* на *import* в кеше:

> C:\Users\ddd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned^4.0.0\index.js:36
> var exported = require(env.configPath);
>
> ^ Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\ddd\Documents\МОИ ПРОЕКТЫ\fmari.ru\code\gulpfile.js from
>
> C:\Users\ddd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned^4.0.0\index.js
> not supported. Instead change the require of gulpfile.js in
>
> C:\Users\ddd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned^4.0.0\index.js
> to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Как можно избавиться от неё?

Answer (score 0):

Решил по [инструкции](https://riptutorial.com/gulp/example/4376/installation-or-setup)
Удалил `gulp`

```
npm rm --global gulp
```

Затем, заново глобально проинициализировал `gulp-cli`

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Установил `gulp` в проект с зависимостями

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

И запустил дефолтный таск `gulp`. Заработало!